# How can i go to specific activity after main activity has been started?

Tags: appium, appium-android

```
    @caps['name'] = 'Ruby Appium Example'
    @caps['deviceName'] = @device_name
    @caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    @caps['noReset'] = true
    @caps['fullReset'] = false
   
    @caps['appPackage'] = 'com.xyz.abc'
    @caps['app'] = './apk/xyz.apk'
    @caps['appActivity'] = 'com.xyz.abc.activity.SplashScreenActivity'
    @caps
```

```
 @appium_driver = Appium::Driver.new(
      {
        'caps' => @caps,
        'appium_lib' =>
        {
          server_url: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'
        }
      }, true
    )
```

```
 @appium_driver.start_driver
```

Suppose I want to go to the `TestScreenActivity` directly after the lunch of `SplashScreenActivity`. How can i do it?

I am using `ruby` with `appium_lib`

Answer (score 0):

```
# ruby_lib example
start_activity app_package: "com.example", app_activity: "ActivityName"

# ruby_lib_core example
@driver.start_activity app_package: "com.example", app_activity: "ActivityName"
```

You can always check Appium API in [official docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/activity/start-activity/)